# ManyToMany Parent and Child Side In JPA

Tags: jpa, hibernate-mapping

**Technology Stack :**

JPA 2.2

**Issue :**

How to decide parent and child in a `@ManyToMany` association  ?

Consider below use case :

I have a `User entity and Product entity.`
A user can subscribe to multipule products and a product can be subscribed by many users.

My question is :

1)How to decide which is a parent entity and child entity ? In other words who will carry the `mappedBy` attribute ?

2)Because depending on this decision , we will model the entity classes

3)In case of `@OneToMany` , it is the one side which contains `mappedBy` attribute and hence Many side controls the association

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer, it depends on what your system thinks is best. The relationship will only be persisted when entries are put in the owning side so you have to ask yourself whether you more commonly change a user's list of products or a product's list of users. If `User` owns the relationship then you update the relationship by adding or removing products from a user instance but if you had a list of users for a product that you wanted to persist you would need to iterate through the list and alter each user.